# How to refer to a drop down list by name using jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I need to refer to a drop down list by its name.

html

```
 <select name="myName"></select>
```

Comment: I would add that `name` is not HTML5 compliant.

Comment: Quick look in the doc : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a select element with id my-drop-down like this :

```
<select name="myName" id='my-drop-down'></select>
```

You can refer it like this:

```
var referenceToDropDown = $('#my-drop-down');
```

OR like this:

```
 var referenceToDropDown = $('select[name = "myName"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector like:

```
$("select[name='myName']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector:

```
$('[name="myName"]');
```